# Change opencart requests to thrift binaries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thrift, opencart2.x, thrift-protocol

We are using opencart for our ecommerce framework.Lately we are being limited by the resources and features and opencart becoming a bottleneck for implementing those features.Now we are shifting to Ruby On Rails.How can we use thrift to make use of already built opencart project and convert the request calls to thrift bundles?

Comment: Instead of re-posting the (basically) [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505045/opencart-and-thrift) over and over again, it could be much more helpful to outline the scenario in a more detailed manner. As it stands, the question is both "offtopic" and "too broad" and will very likely be put [on hold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question) for one of these two reasons.

Comment: Im Sorry,I will rephrase the question appropriately